# Validate whether all projects are using the Authentication and Authorizations SDK's or not

Tags: c#, .net, dll, sdk

Few C# SDK's(dlls) are developed to Authenticate and Authorize. Requirement is to force or validate if all the projects in the company are using these SDK's or not. If the Projects are not using SDK's then they should be forced to use them and then should validate if they are following all standards or not. Looking for some solutions for this requirement.

Some of the solutions I am thinking of:

1. Tools which validates whether Projects are implementing the SDK's or not.
2. CI/CD Pipeline.

Comment: Are your "projects" by any chance microservices?

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh Few projects will be MicroServices but few projects will be still Monolithic..

Comment: Anyway, these are some "services" with probably REST or similar APIs, access to which must be protected. Just an idea, not an answer: implement a public API gateway that will take over auth in one place. Hide your services behind. Like this, you don't have to check which project uses which library for auth, it's all implemented in exactly one place.

Comment: Otherwise CI/CD pipeline sounds like a good idea. You could add Powershell/Bash steps there, so pretty much everything is possible. However the fact, that a project references an SDK does not guarantee, it uses it in a correct way. That would be close to impossible I would say, as it would involve code inspection. Just imagine the "hell" if at some point you get a Python service with its own SDK.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh already public API gateway is in place. Want to enforce this validation during development process itself so that rework can be avoided.